# jQuery v1.4.2 (hide, appendTo and fadeIn) + IE v10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

Sorry for the cryptic title but I discovered something weird using jQuery v1.4.2 and IE v10.

This works for firefox, safari and chrome but not for IE:

```
// Hides container, appends data to it and slowly fades it in
$(data.element).hide().appendTo(message_td).fadeIn(400);
```

This works for all browsers including IE

```
// Hides container, appends data to it and slowly fades it in
$(data.element).appendTo(message_td).hide().fadeIn(400);
```

Is this IE's problem or jQuery's problem and has it been fixed in newer jQuery versions?

EDIT: Why is this happening? Is IE hiding the container and fadeInning the content inside the hidden container?

Comment: "*has it been fixed in newer jQuery versions*" ... have you tried it? (hint: *lots* of things have been fixed since jQuery 1.4.1, and also IE10 didn't exist when jQuery 1.4.2 was released. I'd say there's a pretty good chance there are going to be issues with it in IE10)

Comment: What errors do you see in IE10's console?

Comment: No errors. It just hides the element and doesn't fade it in.